# Customer Balance Aging Report

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-cursor

I am trying to build a report on SQL server which will provide a customer's average days of due settlement.
here's the sample table from which i want to generate report from

| Customer | Date | Debit | Credit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 2021-04-01 | 10000 | 0 |
| abc | 2021-04-08 | 0 | 3000 |
| abc | 2021-05-02 | 1000 | 1000 |
| abc | 2021-06-09 | 0 | 2000 |
| abc | 2021-07-10 | 2000 | 1000 |
| abc | 2021-08-11 | 0 | 4000 |
| abc | 2021-09-10 | 0 | 3000 |

Here I am trying to generate a report that the customer abc had cleared the due to $10000 which he owed on 2021-04-01 was cleared on 2021-08-11 and which the customer took 132 days to clear and the second due ($1000) owed on 2021-05-02 was cleared on 2021-08-21 which took 101 days and the due of $2000 made on 2021-07-10 was cleared on 2021-09-10 which took 62 days to clear.
so the desired output is

| Customer | settlement_days |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 132 |
| abc | 101 |
| abc | 62 |

I tried to do this with SQL cursors but I was stuck after I got the result 132. Please find the code below

```
begin
        declare @date as date        
        declare @debit as int
        declare @debit1 as int=0
        declare @credit as int
        declare @credit1 as int=0
        declare @balance as int=0
        declare @date1 as date
        declare @i as int=0
        declare @count as int
        declare @k as int=0


        declare closing scroll cursor for
        select convert(date,date),debit,credit from samples
        select  @count= count(debit) from samples
        open closing
        fetch next from closing into @date, @debit, @credit ;
        while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
        begin
        set @balance=@credit-@debit
        set @date1=@date
        set @debit1=@debit
        while @@FETCH_STATUS=0 

        begin
                set @balance=@balance+@credit
                set @credit1=@credit1+@credit
                set @i=@i+@debit
                if (@k<=@debit1)
                begin
                    set @k=@k+@debit
                end
                
                if @balance>0
                begin 
                        print(datediff(day,@date1,@date))
                        print (@credit1-@debit1)
                        print (@k)
                        break
        
                end
                fetch next from closing into @date, @debit, @credit;
                
        end
        fetch next from closing into @date, @debit, @credit;
        end
        
        close closing
        deallocate closing
end
```

I am stuck here about not knowing how to proceed further

Comment: `the due of $2000 made on 2021-07-10 was cleared on 2021-09-10 which took 153 days to clear.` How do you get 153 ? shouldn't it be just 62 ?

Comment: Sorry I miscalculated ,gotta edit that

Comment: `second due ($1000) owed on 2021-05-02 was cleared on 2021-08-21 which took 101 days` just to be sure, the debt can be clared without transaction? i cant find that particular date in the record..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using window function `sum() over ()` to find cumulative sum for Total Debit and Total Credit. After that find earliest date where Total Credit >= Total Debit. That's the settlement date

```
with 
debit as
(
    select  *, 
            -- cumulative sum
            sum(Debit) over(partition by Customer order by [Date]) as Dr
    from    samples s
    where   Debit   > 0
),
credit as
(
    select  *, 
            -- cumulative sum
            sum(Credit) over(partition by Customer order by [Date]) as Cr
    from    samples s
    where   Credit  > 0
)
select  *, datediff(day, dr.[Date], cr.[Date]) as SettlementDays
from    debit dr
        cross apply
        (
            select  top 1 cr.[Date]
            from    credit cr
            where   cr.Customer  = dr.Customer
            and     cr.Cr       >= dr.Dr
        ) cr
order by dr.Customer, dr.[Date]
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=810699bf31d3ab2dedd4735d66f07572)